# PHP display image from file path in browser

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to display an image from the file path but it did return me an error which is "Not allowed to load local resource" i do not know what is the error. I have tried found many resources but it still cannot fix it. Can someone help me on it? Here is the code

'pic.php'

```
<?php

echo "<img src='F:\xampp\htdocs\8DReportSystem\uploadd\Desert.jpg'></img>";

?>
```

I knew that this topic have been duplicated, but i just tried all the related topics but it would not fix the error yet. i do not know what is the error. Can someone help me pls.

Comment: where your pic.php stored, I mean what is your project root folder? is it 8DReportSystem?

Comment: Why you tagged javascript?

Comment: Are you specifically trying to load this image via the file system, and not via HTTP? (If so - why?) This should probably rather just be something like `src="/8DReportSystem/uploadd/Desert.jpg"`, assuming the root of your web project points to the `F:\xampp\htdocs` folder.

Comment: @04FS erm ya, the file path is not correct??

Answer (score 0):

You have to use path related to your project root folder, for eg. let's say you've project in your **F:\xampp\htdocs\8DReportSystem** folder and your images are in ****F:\xampp\htdocs\8DReportSystem\uploadd**** folder then your code looks like

```
<?php

    echo "<img src='uploadd\Desert.jpg'></img>";

?>
```

Comment: if let say the file path is store at database and i want to call out, and then it also will pop out same error. so how do i resolve it. Do you have any example?

Comment: Are you saving **relative** file path in database? If it is so then use `echo "<img src='".$yourQueryResult->path."'></img>";`. If not then save relative file path in database.